# Git adds my all folders except client folder

Tags: node.js, git, github

I have a node.js app and an additional client folder for front end.
Unfortunately, I'm unable to add my client subfolders to my repositories(.gitignore checked). Probably because the client folder has its own package.json file. How can I add the subfiles of the client folder? My folder structure as follows;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNtPB.png)

Comment: It's not due to the `package.json` file. It's *probably* due to the fact that the client folder *is* a Git repository (whether it is or is not is not clear to me from the image though). A repository cannot store another repository; it can only store a *reference to* another repository.

Comment: Your choices include: remove the other *repository* entirely (leaving only one set of files, not yet versioned, which you can now store and version in the higher-level repository), or use `git submodule` to have the outer repository store a *reference to* another repository. There are other options but these are the main two.